# Choosing characters for list arrays to set a conditional

Tags: python

I have created a function for checking the presence of characters from a list array.  I know what characters will give a positive result, but the characters that denote a negative result could be anything that's not on the list of positive characters.  When a character appears on the list array, I want it to be counted by appended to a new list.

I have this so far, but I can't get the function to recognize the characters that I don't want. Everything is a negative result. I know why its a negative result, but I cant setup a conditional check that has ['M','W','A','N',...] a list that contains characters and can be in any position.

```
def sequence_compare(seq_1, seq_2,):
    len1= len(seq_1)
    len2= len(seq_2)
    error_list =[]
    for pos in range (0,min(len1,len2)):
        if seq_1 or seq_2 != ['M','W','A','N','G']:
            error_list.append('*')
        else:
            error_list.append(' ')
    print (seq_1)
    print (error_list)
    print (seq_2)
    print ("Number of Error:")
    print (error_list.count('*'))
seq_1 = ['T','W','A','N']
seq_2 = ['T','R','A','L']
sequence_compare(seq_1, seq_2)
```

EDIT I should clarify that I am looking for an output that looks like this:

```
['T', 'W', 'A', 'N']
[' ', ' ', ' ', '*']
['T', 'R', 'A', '!']
Number of Error:
1
```

Where '!' is not one of the characters, amongst others that I want to return as an Error. But 'T', 'W', 'R', 'A' and 'N' amongst others that I do know already, ARE the characters that I don't want to return as an Error. As 'W' and 'R' show they don't need to be matching for it to be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution, you are comparing a string and an array. The result is always false and thus '*', because a string and an array always don't equal each other.

What you want, is to check every **character** from both strings. To do that, you can use the `in` operator. It should have following syntax in your case:

```
if your_string[pos] in ['symbol1', 'symbol2', ...]:
    print("Yes, symbol in string 'your_string' on position 'pos' is one of the listed symbols")
else:
    print("No, symbol in string 'your_string' on position 'pos' is not in the list")
```

The resulting code will be like this:

```
def sequence_compare(seq_1, seq_2,):
    len1= len(seq_1)
    len2= len(seq_2)
    error_list =[]
    for pos in range (0,min(len1,len2)):
        if seq_1[pos] not in ['M','W','A','N','G'] or seq_2[pos] not in ['M','W','A','N','G']:
            error_list.append('*')
        else:
            error_list.append(' ')
    print (seq_1)
    print (error_list)
    print (seq_2)
    print ("Number of Error:")
    print (error_list.count('*'))
seq_1 = ['T','W','A','N']
seq_2 = ['T','R','A','L']
sequence_compare(seq_1, seq_2)
```

With the output:

```
['T', 'W', 'A', 'N']
['*', '*', ' ', '*']
['T', 'R', 'A', 'L']
Number of Error:
3
```

EDIT:
The code above is how I understood your task. If the output differs from the desired, you need to work with `not` and `or/and` operators to get a correct solution.

Comment: Hi, I checked with the 'not in' adjustment instead of != that now has the desired output. Thanks!